# Oracle AQ dequeue-ing parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql, advanced-queuing

I'm trying to dequeue messages from Oracle queueue and am having trouble with setting up dequeue_options. I am trying to dequeue messages that have ENQ_TIME greater than input value (timestamp).
I managed to dequeue messages wihout parameters or by msgid or by enq_tid.
I used

```
dequeue_options.deq_condition := 'tab.enq_tid = ''' || i_enq_tid || ''''
```

and that is working.
When i try to do the same with enq_time i get an error that there are no mesages.
I have tried to use the > symbol and different to_char conversion strings on both sides of the operator and can't get it to work.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could dequeue, hold the MSGID and if the ENQ_TIME is lower than your date input, then update the state to 0 using the said MSGID at your queue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a cursor on queue table to extract relevent msgid-s. Then access messages by msgid.
However I have a feeling that the right deq_condition should work. There must be a better way out there.